# Papyrus UML class symbol, getting started

Tags: eclipse, uml, papyrus

Do I miss some specific styles or settings? What is wrong in my installation?

I am trying to create my first Papyrus class diagram, but when adding a new class, the shape is only an empty square with the name. How can I get the normal shape with attributes and operations?

[image: Class diagram]

Comment: You did try to add attributes/operations, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, there are some. Should I install specific styles or something?